# Yii. I can't get model attribute on another server

Tags: php, yii

The first server has PHP Version 5.3.29
The second server has PHP Version 5.4.40
On the first server everything is OK, everything work as necessary.
But on the second server I can't get model attributes that are model columns.

On the second server
`var_dump($model)`
will show me

```
object(PaymentApplication)#439 (11) {
  ["_new":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_attributes":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(7) {
    ["paymentId"]=>
    string(2) "74"
    ["applicationId"]=>
    string(3) "213"
    ["updatedHrs"]=>
    string(4) "3.00"
    ["adjustment"]=>
    string(4) "0.00"
    ["remarks"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["briefingHrs"]=>
    string(4) "0.00"
    ["variable"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["_related":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_c":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_pk":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["paymentId"]=>
    string(2) "74"
    ["applicationId"]=>
    string(3) "213"
  }
  ["_alias":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  string(1) "t"
  ["_errors":"CModel":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_validators":"CModel":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_scenario":"CModel":private]=>
  string(6) "update"
  ["_e":"CComponent":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_m":"CComponent":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

But if I write `$model->paymentId` (or any other attribute that is presents in the DB) I'm getting the error `Trying to get property of non-object`.
Also `$model->getAttribute('paymentId');` will return me the value, but I need directly get value of model attributes (also I need to get the access to relations).
For my experience I've never faced with that problem. Any ideas?
Maybe there are some problems because of PHP versions?

Comment: your table schema might be cached, try removing all items in `protected/runtime` folder

Comment: @tinybyte Unfortunately it didn't help. After clearing of `protected/runtime`, the error still same.